# Convert Datetime format from DD-MON-YY HH:mm:ss.mmmmmmmmm AM/PM to YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.mmmmmmm ( 24 Hr Format )

Tags: sql-server, date

Convert Datetime format from DD-MON-YY HH:mm:ss.mmmmmmmmm AM/PM to YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.mmmmmmm ( 24 Hr Format )

ex : - 
"04-SEP-12 06.03.45.519068000 PM"
to
"12-09-04 18:03:45.5190680M"

Comment: `DATETIME` doesn't have a format in SQL Server, it's a binary data. Unless you are storing it as formatted string.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is an outdated Java class. I assumed it wasn’t relevant here and removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the value is a `varchar` of the format is `dd-MMM-yy hh.mi.ss.mmmmmmmmm AM(PM)`, rather than what is in your title, this converts the value to a `datetime2(7)`. You would then control the format it is **displayed** as in your presentation layer:

```
DECLARE @date varchar(35) = '04-SEP-12 06.03.45.519068000 PM';

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(V.D,13,1,':'),16,1,':'),27,2,''),9)
FROM (VALUES(@date)) V(D);
```